# Django model is inheriting 'password' field from another model with it's PK and showing in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Edit: + Patient

While I was checking my code, i noticed that some models have the property "password" as a DB column in PostgreSQL and that those models don't have that attribute, the only relationship between the attribute "password" and the table is that the table's model has a FK pointing to a model which is a AbstractBaseUser extension.

```
django = ">=2.1.0"
djangorestframework = ">=3.9.2"
flake8 = ">=3.6.0,<3.7.0"
autopep8 = "*"
psycopg2 = "<2.8.0,>=2.7.5"
django-organizations = "==1.1.2"
django-countries = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"


from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, \
    PermissionsMixin
import datetime
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

# Create your models here.


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

  def create_user(self, email, password = None, ** kwargs):
  ""
"Creates and saves a new User"
""
if not email:
  raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
user = self.model(email = self.normalize_email(email), ** kwargs)
user.set_password(password)
user.is_staff = False
user.is_active = True
user.is_doctor = False
user.save(using = self._db)

return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password, ** kwargs):
  ""
"Creates and saves a new super user"
""
user = self.create_user(email, password, ** kwargs)
user.is_staff = False
user.is_active = True
user.is_doctor = False
user.is_superuser = True
user.save(using = self._db)

return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  ""
"Custom user model that supports using email instead of username"
""
email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254, unique = True)
firstName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
middleName = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True)
firstSurname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
lastSurname = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)
passwordHint = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)
creationDate = models.DateField(
  default = datetime.date.today, blank = False, null = False)
lastLoginDate = models.DateField(
  blank = True, null = True)
lastPasswordResetDate = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(
  default = True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(
  default = False)
is_doctor = models.BooleanField(
  default = False)
externalUserCode = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)

objects = UserManager()
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

class Doctor(AbstractBaseUser):
    """Custom user that has the information of the doctors"""
    doctorID = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    specialtyID = models.ManyToManyField(DoctorSpecialties)
    identificationTypeID = models.ForeignKey('generic.IdentificationType',
                                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    identificationTypeNumber = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999999999)])

class Patient(AbstractBaseUser):
    """Custom user that has the information of the patient"""
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    identificationType = models.ForeignKey('genericWS.IdentificationType',
                                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    identificationNumber = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    patientAddress = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
```

The issue is that i have a column name "password" for tables public.noteapp_patient and public.noteapp_doctor which I don't know exactly why they are there, since I'm not declaring that property in the model.

Comment: What is your question? Doctor clearly inherits from AbstractBaseUser. (You haven't shown Patient.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman the question is why is it showing a "password" column when i migrate to postgres

Comment: Because it inherits from AbstractBaseUser, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel wrote in the comments, this is expected behaviour. Your classes `Doctor` and `Patient` inherit from `AbstractBaseUser`, thus they will also have the [fields defined in AbstractBaseUser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L47), which are `password`, `last_login` and `is_active`

Check out the [django documentation on abstract base model classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) for more information about this.
If the concept of inheritance is new to you, you can find some tutorials (e.g. [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp)) explaining that on the internet.

Also, it looks like you want to use polymorphism for `User`, `Doctor` and `Patient` there. You may want to take a look at [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which can help a lot with that.

Comment: That answers my question and an ongoing issue related to being able to create sub-users from a abse user class, many thanks.